# Laravel - Is it possible to have many-to-many relationship with one table and a pivot table

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, relationship

I have a pivot table named `user_ranks` although I knew it had to be `rank_user`. In this table I have these columns:

`ranker_id`(user_id), `car_id`, `rank`

In `users` table I have `user_id` column and so on...

And in `cars` table I have `car_id` and so on...

What I want is to get all cars from `cars` table and get the `avg` of `rank` column in `user_ranks` table related to each car.

What I had done before in controller and without using any model was:

```
$car = \DB::table('cars')
    ->selectRaw('*, AVG(user_ranks.rank) rank_avg, car.car_id car_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.user_id', 'car.user_id')
    ->leftJoin('user_ranks', 'user_ranks.car_id', 'cars.car_id')
    ->where('cars.car_id', $carId)
    ->groupBy('cars.car_id')
    ->first();
```

however now I want to use model but (I think) there is no need for that because in that table I would have `id`, `rank` which the data are from 1 to 5 for both `id` and `rank`. They are static and it's not going to insert some data there.

So is it possible to have a relation between cars and its ranks (many-to-many relation) with two tables without that extra table?

Thanks

Comment: could you show schema of tables? `users` ,`cars`,`user_ranks`

Comment: What is the ‍‍`ranks` table fields?

Comment: I don't have any table named `ranks`. As I said I have `ranker_id`(user_id), `car_id`, `rank` in `user_ranks` table, `user_id`, `username`, `password` in `users` table and `car_id`, `car_code` in `cars` table. Thanks @Alihosseinshahabi

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this :

`Car` mode :

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Car extends Model
{
    protected $tables='cars';

    public function ranks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserRanks::class,'car_id','car_id');
    }
}
```

`UserRanks` model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserRanks extends Model
{
    protected $table='user_ranks';
}
```

your `controller` :

```
# get all cars with their ranks
$cars=Car::with(['ranks'=>function($query){
    $query->select('car_id','rank');
}])->get();

# added `avg_ranks` field to result
$cars->each(function ($item, $key) {
    $item->avg_ranks=$item->ranks->avg('rank');
});

#print result 
dd($cars->toArray());
```

result :

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "car_id" => 1
    "car_code" => "1111"
    "avg_ranks" => 4.5
    "ranks" => array:2 [▶]
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "car_id" => 2
    "car_code" => "2222"
    "avg_ranks" => null
    "ranks" => []
  ]
]
```